# Playonlinux shortcut error with Office 2010 on wine

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft

Always get this error while giving the 2010 office setup... any solutions?

```
Error in POL_Shortcut
Binary not found: POWERPNT.EXE
Have you installed the program to the default location?
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow instructions from this link:

https://gist.github.com/raelgc/4ccc023830bfd12c0227

It worked on Ubuntu 18.10, for both MS Office 2007 and 2010